# Criteria in Query Design to equal this year's data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, criteria

**Background**

- My data field InvoiceDate looks like MM/DD/YYYY ex) 11/4/2017
- User enters date parameter through `Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]`
- This Year sum field criteria is `Year([InvoiceDate])=Year(Date())`

**Problem** When User enter [BeginDate]=10/1/2017 And [EndDate]=10/31/2017, 
My This year's $ sum includes *current month* (November)'s data as well.

**Goal** I want to parse months, from January upto `Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]`'s month of current year

Any help would be highly appreciated!

**Update**: I have tried

`Year([InvoiceDate])=Year(Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate])<=Month(Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate])`

But I'm getting ODBC failed error. is it because it's a long criteria?

Comment: try [invoice date]>= [begindate] and [invoicedate]<=[enddate]

Comment: @DonGeorge thank you for the comment. But the begin date is for example, 10/1/2017, and end date is 10/31/2017. How can It populate months from January?

Comment: Are you trying to get the year-to-date value for Jan - Oct when the criteria are Oct 1 to Oct 31?

Comment: @JohnMo Yes sir! that is correct. Sorry If my explanation was not good enough

Comment: then year([invoice date])=year([enddate]) and [invoice date]<=[enddate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start and end dates in different years are possibly a problem, but this criteria string will always give you YTD for the year of the EndDate:

```
[InvoiceDate] <= [EndDate] AND [InvoiceDate] >= "1/1/" & Year([EndDate])
```

You could use BETWEEN if you like too:

```
[InvoiceDate] BETWEEN "1/1/" & Year([EndDate]) AND [EndDate]
```